# AJAX and ASPSTATE

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session-state

we've been having quite a lot of problems with our application which has intermittent performance problems which uses the ASPSTATE to manage its session state. At high volumes, we're seeing a lot of blocking with the session tables in ASPSTATE causing user response to degrade significantly.

We've followed a lot of recommendations provided by Microsoft through KB articles and consultants - including the update to the PurgeSession stored proc and also amending this to be scheduled every 5 mins (from 10 mins). Still no luck though.

Having read through numerous blogs, none of the suggestions seem to be able to help - our session size are quite small (14k on average), though we continue to see blocks being caused by TempGetStateItemExclusive3 during our problem periods.

The application uses AJAX in elements - and I've seen one comment in this blog which suggests that the use of AJAX and ASPSTATE could have potential problems. Has anyone come across this and what to get around it?
http://www.rjp-software.co.uk/blog/2010/03/asp-net-sessions-with-sql-server/

Our current plot is to move to INPROC session state using a sticky load balancer though it'd be good to know if indeed there is a general problem with the use of AJAX and ASPSTATE!! I do find it hard to believe that no other implementation has come across this...

*For info, we have around 4000 clients connected to the application (running across 4 web-app servers). Session table doesn't seem to go above 3500 users at any one time.*

Comment: 14K of session state sounds like a lot.

Comment: We see a similar problem when we reach a high load. Still don't know why it is happening.